# Can you execute MovieClip's gotoAndStop() function in FRAME_CONSTRUCTED event?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I had some problems with using gotoAndStop() function in FRAME_CONSTRUCTED event callback. This lead me to assumption that **YOU CANNOT** do that?

This time I tried to do something like this:

```
public function init() : void {
    someMC.addEventListener( Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED, function ( e:Event ) : void {
        MovieClip( e.target ).someChild.gotoAndStop(1);
    });
}
```

Surprisingly, this time this throwed me a stack overflow error!

Can this be any true?

Comment: Try to add this check before call _gotoAndStop_: _if(MovieClip( e.target ).someChild.currentFrame != 1)_

Comment: Mu function was more extended than this ( it was checking if the frame is not the same, if someChild exists ).

Answer (score 0):

The frame constructed event runs right before the frame is drawn. This is what's happening.

`Your movie clip is about to render frame 2.`

`The event fires. Your movie clip goes to frame 1.`

`Your movie clip is about to render frame 1.`

`The event fires. Your movie clip goes to frame 1.`

And this repeats forever.

Comment: But does it still apply, when I am changing the frame of child ( not of the object i am listening to? )

Comment: It could be that the event is bubbling up from the child. Use `trace(e.target);trace(e.currentTarget);trace(e.target.name);trace(e.currentTarget.name)` to figure out what's going on